# Custom handlebars each helper with index

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I wrote a helper that loops over an array, but now I'm stuck at getting the index available for each iteration. I wish in my view to print the index of the current item.

```
helpers: {
    each_min: function(ary, min, options) {
      if(!ary || ary.length == 0)
          return options.inverse(this);

      var result = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < min; ++i)
          result.push(options.fn(ary[i]));
      return result.join('');
    }
}
```

My template

```
{{#each_min p.name 4}}
{{#if this}}
{{index}} {{this}}
{{else}}
<p>-</p>
{{/if}}
{{/each_min}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking through handlebars docs I found relevant info in the [Block helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#hash-arguments) section.

> Block helpers can also inject private variables into their child templates. This can be useful to add extra information that is not in the original context data. ... Make sure you create a new data frame in each helper that assigns its own data. Otherwise, downstream helpers might unexpectedly mutate upstream variables.

Based on that I made these changes:

**template**:

```
{{#each_min p.name 4}}
    {{#if this}}
        {{@index}} {{this}}
    {{else}}
        <p>-</p>
    {{/if}}
{{/each_min}}
```

**helper**:

```
function(ary, min, options) {
    if(!ary || ary.length === 0) {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
    var data;
    if (options.data) {
        data = Handlebars.createFrame(options.data);
    }

    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < min; ++i) {
        if (data) {
            data.index = i;
        }
        result.push(options.fn(ary[i], {data: data}));
    }

    return result.join('');
}
```